# Wix: How can I point `C:\Windows\hh.exe` as the source of the icon for my CHM-file shortcut?

Tags: wix, shortcut, chm

I need to create the shortcut to my CHM-file. Its icon are to be gotten from the `C:\Windows\hh.exe` file. The `Icon` attribute requires an `Id` of component, but `hh.exe` is absent in my MSI because it always exists in the `C:\Windows\` directory. Therefore it will not work:

```
<Component Id="Help_default" Guid="{BE58A822-637E-4B58-B2AC-690BA9FDF833}">
  <File Name="ProxyTools.chm" KeyPath="yes">
    <Shortcut Id="ProxyTools.exe" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" 
              Name="ProxyTools (English)" 
              WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Advertise="yes" Icon="hh.exe" IconIndex="0"/>
  </File>
</Component>
```

Maybe I am to point  somehow the `hh.exe` like the item of

```
<Directory Id="WindowsFolder"/>
```

How can I point `C:\Windows\hh.exe` as the source of the icon for my CHM-file shortcut?

**UPD**

I added `hh.exe` into my WiX project and added this:

```
<Icon Id="hh.exe" SourceFile="hh.exe"/>
```

Now shortcuts is right.

Comment: Except now you have to consult your Windows EULA on redistributing hh.exe.I would look for an .ico file that's covered by my licenses. (And then rename it, surprisingly, "hh.ico.exe".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer does not make this possible. To understand the exact capability set, you must examine the underlying tables. First the [Shortcut table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371847.aspx) Icon column is "The external key to column one of the [Icon table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369210.aspx)." The Icon table contains a primary key (referred to by the shortcut table, among others) and a binary entry. The binary data is the icon data to use.

Since the actual icon data must be stored in the resulting .msi database, and there are no alternate ways to specify an icon, you cannot refer to an icon that may already exist on the system. You can copy the desired icon into a resource of the Icon table, but that's as close as you can come with native Windows Installer functionality.

Comment: As luck would have it, I found the "hh.exe" icon left over from the installation of the WiX Toolset, a file called `WixSetupIcons.ico`.

Answer (score 0):

A [WixEdit](https://wixedit.github.io/) example including a separate icon file for the User Guide shortcut icon.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="some-guid" Name="MyApp" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.4" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="some-guid">
        <Package Description="An application with a user guide" Comments="Packed with WixEdit" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="files.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="MYAPP" Name="MyApp">

                    <Component Id="APPHELP.CHM" DiskId="1" Guid="some-guid">
                        <File Id="APPHELP.CHM" Name="AppHelp.chm" Source="Sources\Files\AppHelp.chm">
                            <Shortcut Id="HelpShortcut" Name="MyApp User Guide" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Advertise="yes" Icon="HelpIcon.ico" />
                        </File>
                    </Component>

                    <Component Id="APPHELP.ICO" DiskId="1" Guid="some-guid">
                        <File Id="APPHELP.ICO" Name="AppHelp.ico" Source="Sources\Files\AppHelp.ico" />
                    </Component>

                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="MyCompany">
                    <Component Id="StartMenuShortcuts" Guid="some-guid">
                        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
                        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="APPHELP.CHM" />
            <ComponentRef Id="StartMenuShortcuts" />
            <ComponentRef Id="APPHELP.ICO" />
        </Feature>
        
        <Icon Id="HelpIcon.ico" SourceFile="Sources\Files\AppHelp.ico" />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```