# InstallShield - shortcut icon file on target machine

Tags: icons, installshield

I'm developing an (InstallScript MSI) installer for a self-hosted ASP.NET Core application.  (Using InstallShield 2015.)

We are in fact generating an .EXE (rather than a DLL) for the ASP.NET app, but there doesn't seem to be a way to embed an icon into the output .EXE.  (I don't see anything in the docs for `project.json` options, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507944/set-the-application-icon-in-net-core-1-0-web-api-projects) has gone unanswered.)

Since this is an InstallScript MSI project, I can't create an Internet shortcut, at least not using the designer.  So I created one myself and added it to the install project.  I'm creating "regular"/non-Internet shortcuts on the Desktop and Start Menu pointing to the Internet shortcut.  I'd like to assign an icon to these shortcuts.

According to the docs, if you use the *Display Resource* setting to specify a resource DLL from which to get the icon, you can specify a folder on the target machine using MSI properties e.g. `[INSTALLDIR]\MyAppResources.dll`.

However, if you specify the icon using the *Icon File* and *Icon Index* settings, it appears you can't use MSI properties, only path variables, so even though I'm deploying the .ico to the target system I can't point the shortcut at it.
(For the interested ... if you try to specify the icon file using an MSI property, what happens is you get almost to the end of the build process -- it's after the media table gets built -- and then you get an error.)

Yes, I can point the icon to a resource on the build system.  And the shortcut does get created with the icon, but the icon points at `%SystemRoot%\Installer\{someguid}.exe`.  This concerns me because I've known people who clear out folders like this one when they're running short on disk space.

I understand that I could embed the icon in a DLL; or alternatively I could generate the .url files (Internet shortcuts) "by hand" using file I/O.  But why should I need to?  This seems like a silly limitation.  If I can pull an icon from a DLL on the target system, why can't I specify an .ICO file on the target system?  Is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37657063) address your question? (You're right that DisplayResourceDLL's docs indicate it can be any formatted string, but it doesn't provide the icon, so isn't relevant even pointing to a pre-existing file works.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight.  But I'm not sure this does answer the question.  Based on your link, it sounds like InstallShield is doing something beyond what is supported by MSI i.e. extracting the icon from the DLL and inserting the bytes into the *Icon* table.  However that still doesn't tell me why I can specify a .DLL but not an .ICO on the target system as the source of the icon data.